# Can't make my example using std::ranges::copy_if(R&& r, O result, Pred pred, Proj proj = {}) compile

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20, std-ranges

I've reduced the code failing to compile to the one below:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/fsE363jzs)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // copy_if
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // back_inserter
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    std::string p{};
    std::string d{};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v{{"/usr/bin/cat", "blah"}, {"/usr/lib", "foo"}};
    std::vector<std::string> o{};
    std::ranges::copy_if(
        v,
        std::back_inserter(o),
        [](std::string& p){ return (p.size() > 10); },
        &A::p);
}
```

Visual Studio's error output is quite short: `error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Copy_if_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied.` It basically points you to check the constraints of `copy_if` at the `algorithm` header.

gcc and clang are more detailed. Having a look at a bit of both outputs:

- First, the `copy_if` overload with a range, an output iterator, a predicate, and a projection, is considered.
- But then, the expression `*__o = (std::forward<_Tp>(__t)` is evaluated as invalid; where: `'_Out&& __o', '_Tp&& __t' [with _Tp = A&; _Out = std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string>>]`

Since we are using a projection (from `A&` to `std::string&`), why is it trying to copy an `A&` instead of a `std::string&` to `o`?

The full error output is accessible through the Demo link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection applies only to the predicate, not to the result. There's already a way to transform the data entirely—`std::views::transform`:

```
std::ranges::copy_if(
    v | std::views::transform(&A::p),
    std::back_inserter(o),
    [](const std::string& p){ return (p.size() > 10); });
```

(This compiles in GCC and MSVC, but not Clang. I'm not 100% confident saying it's correct, but it should be close if nothing else, and it illustrates the point.)

Projections are for when you want to test a transformation (projection) of the data while carrying the originals through. In this example, that would mean you'd output to `std::vector<A>`, yet test a `std::string` in the predicate. Not super useful here since you could just `return (a.p.size() > 10);`, but useful if passing a pre-written function instead of using a lambda. Also useful for some other cases such as easily sorting by a member—simply use the default comparator and pass `&A::p` as the projection.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, the code version, and the explanation about projections. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Since we are using a projection (from A& to std::string&), why is it trying to copy an A& instead of a std::string& to o?

Because that's what the algorithm does. `copy_if` always copies the source range into the provided iterator, for each element that satisfies the predicate.

The projection only affects the predicate - it's basically just doing function composition here - but it doesn't affect what the overall algorithm does.

This is true for all projections.

If what you want to copy are just the `p` subobjects, what you want to do instead is

```cpp
ranges::copy_if(v | views::transform(&A::p), /* ... */);
```

Which now changes the source range that you're copying from.

---

For more on this topic, I wrote a [whole post](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2022/02/13/projections-function-adaptors/) about it.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, and for providing a working alternative. Sorry I marked the other answer as accepted!

Comment: @rturrado No need to apologize. The other answer is a good answer! For what it's worth, I've seen people have this misunderstanding before, so I updated the answer with a blog post I just wrote about it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Haha, brilliant. I'm sure it will help. Many thanks!